# In GCP PubSub if a message has to be retried does it get pushed to the back of the existing messages before a retry attempt if backoff is configured?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, publish-subscribe

I wanted to check how the retry of a specific message works in GCP pub-sub? If a message has to be retried and if the subscription has other messages does the current one get pushed to the back, or there is no queue at all in GCP pub-sub and the message would be automatically retried between the backoff intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no [retry policy](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#subscription_retry_policy) is set, then a delivered message whose ack deadline expires or is nacked is eligible for redelivery immediately. This means it may be delivered back to the subscriber or to a different subscriber for the same subscription at that moment. There is no notion of "back of the queue" with Google Pub/Sub.

If you do have a retry policy set, then the message does not become eligible for redelivery until the backoff time has passed, at which point it can be sent to the subscriber or to a different subscriber for the same subscription. Note that retry settings are enforced on a best-effort basis, so it is possible under certain circumstances for messages to get redelivered before the backoff time has passed.